# How to select a section of a string from 2 specific points when you cannot use IndexOf in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a program for a school project where I make an `array` and synonyms from a text file that we've been given by creating an object called Word which stores the word and its synonym and then making a class called `WordArray`.

`WordArray`  takes the words and their synonyms from the text file and stores them in the `array` as Word objects.

Then I have a method called `Search()` where a parameter is used to find either all words that partially match the parameter.

For Example: if the parameter is rep, the method will return the words repressed and represent), or one word which is exactly the same as the parameter. If there are multiple words that match the parameter, the method will include a number (starting at 1) and place that before the word.

Now I need to have some code in my main class which takes the `WordArray` (a) and performs the `Search()` method based on a `String` that the user inputs.

I then show the user which words have been found based on their input.

If there is only one word returned, it stores that as the word String, If there are more; I ask the user to input a number that corresponds to the number that is included before the word in the `list of Strings`.

**My problem is**, I want to store that word in the word String, and the last line of code shows what I have done so far. But I would like it in this format:

`word = list.substring(list.indexOf(j), *the character after the end of the word*);`

The issue is I'm not sure how to do that, as I can't use L`astIndexOf` or `IndexOf`, because the **word might be in the middle of a list of multiple words, in which case that wouldn't work**.

**Are there any String methods I could use?**

My code so far is below:

```
String temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a word or part of one:");
   String list = a.Search(temp);
   String word = "";
   System.out.println(list);
   if (list.charAt(0) != '1')
   {
       word = list;
   }
   else
   {
     String j = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the number of the word you'd like:");
     word = list.substring(list.indexOf(j));
   }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier if `Search` returned a `List` or a`String[]` of words  that match' rather than a single`String` that you have to pick apart?  The found  words were apart in your `Word` array, so why go to the trouble to cobble them together into a `String`, only to have to immediately un-cobble them back into separate words again to present them to the user?

Comment: A 'section of a String from two specific points' is given by the `substring()` method. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think your problem is not with available methods to manipulate a String, rather it's a design issue. If I understand you correctly, you need to ensure that the word String stores the correct word rather a set of words ? please correct me if am wrong and explain in details your desired output when lets say you have a specific set of words. give a clearer example.

Comment: The String[] idea is a great one, a previous part of the assignment where they laid out how I had to make the Search() method was pretty specific but I'll try to see if I can incorporate an array because that would definitely make things much easier. And the way I would explain it is that I'm trying to extract the word that the user selects from the list and store it as word.

Comment: Don't name your methods starting with uppercase letters. In the few milliseconds it takes people to figure out it's a method and not a class name, half of them have already given up on your question.

Answer (score 0):

No validation here and assuming `list` contains something:

```
String temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a word or part of one:"); //pp
String list = a.Search(temp);
System.out.println(list); //"1Apple 2Application"
String input = "";
if(list.contains(" ")) //more than one word ???
{
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the number of the word you'd like:");
}
String number = input;
String result = Arrays.asList(list.split(" ")).stream()
    .filter(e -> e.startsWith(number))
    .findFirst()
    .get(); 
System.out.println(result); //1Apple || 2Application
```